# The cubic interpolation

Tags: interpolation, cubics

I try to understand the cubic interpolation for my studies. The following [website](http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic) says " (1) The four equations above can be rewritten to this (2):" but how? Can anyone explain me the the necessary steps?!

from (1)

```
f(0) = d

f(1) = a + b + c + d

f'(0) = c

f'(1) = 3a + 2b + c
```

to (2)

```
a = 2f(0) - 2f(1) + f'(0) + f'(1)

b = -3f(0) + 3f(1) - 2f'(0) - f'(1)

c = f'(0)

d = f(0)
```

Chris

Comment: Just expand the equations below in terms of the given data. For example, $2f(0) - 2f(1) + f'(0) + f'(1)$, when you substitute for each term, simplifies to $a$.

Comment: can you give me an example for `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
  2f(0) - 2f(1) + f'(0) + f'(1) 
    &= 2d - 2(a+b+c+d) + c + 3a+2b+c 
     = a \\
  -3f(0) + 3f(1) - 2f'(0) - f'(1) 
    &= -3d + 3(a+b+c+d) - 2c - (3a+2b+c) 
     = b
\end{align}

Comment: okey, but expanding doesn't solve it, i understand your step but what is the target?

Comment: omg, i see it, thank you :D